# Eclipse - Slot machine, if and else if increasing an int incorrectly

Tags: java

I am creating a slot machine with swing. The follow code has to check and assign results:

```
// Reset win amount
    winAmount = 0;

    // Checks for winning combinations and increases corresponding values
    if (num[0]==num[1] && num[1]==num[2]){
        winAmount = 4;
        coinsWon = coinsWon + winAmount;
        txtWinMessage.setText("Jackpot! You have won " + winAmount + " !"); 
        txtCoinsWon.setText(coinsWon + " ");

        // A text field for testing - so i can see the math it does
        textField_6.setText(coinsWon + " " + winAmount + " / 0 = 1");
    } else if (num[0]==num[1] || num[0]==num[2] || num[1]==num[2]){
        winAmount = 1;
        coinsWon = coinsWon + winAmount;
        txtWinMessage.setText("You Have Won " + winAmount);
        txtCoinsWon.setText(coinsWon + " ");

        // A text field for testing - so i can see the math it does
        textField_6.setText(coinsWon + " " + winAmount + " / 0 = 1");
    } else {
        txtWinMessage.setText("Sorry, try again");

        // A text field for testing - so i can see the math it does
        textField_6.setText("Went to else. coinsWon = " + coinsWon);
    }
```

The num[0], num[1] and num[2] are generated via this bit:

```
private void setIcon(int i) {
    num[i] = random.nextInt(8);
    slots[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/slotIcon" + num[i] + ".png")));
    counter++;
    if(counter > 50) {
        winAmount = 0;
        getResults();
    }
}
```

The testing fields I have show me that the num[i] gets assigned correctly and the ImageIcons are set correctly according to num[i] too. Though problems occur when it comes to the result math. If it goes to the IF part it adds +4 to coinsWon, if to goes to the ELSE IF it adds +1 to coinsWon, though if it goes to ELSE sometimes it doesn't add anything as it should, but sometimes it adds +1 to coinsWon or even +2. But not because winAmount would be 1, but because coinsWon just changes to a bigger number without any apparent reason..

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your last paragraph?

Comment: Basically, if it goes to the } else { section sometimes the coinsWon still gets increased.

Comment: I'd suggest that you debug it.

Comment: Consider that you don't update the "txtCoinsWon" value for the `else` leg, so it will show the prior value.

Comment: Well I don't update the txtCoinsWon value on the else leg, but it still updates the txtCoinsWon and coinsWon values even if it goes to the else leg.

Comment: If you can give us values for which particular behavior happens, we can likely help you understand it.  If you don't do that, you're just asking us to guess which values might do some thing you (sort of) describe, and debug it for you.  I'm guessing the problem might not even be in the incomplete code you give us.   How about "for array values 2, 2, 4, I get x = purple and y = kumquat", or whatever the problem is, rather than assuming that statements in and out of your paths don't execute correctly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, though I'v figured it out with the Debug (completely forget about that tool - I'm really new at this.) The problem was in the `if(counter > 50){` as the counter would go over 50 in two separate occasions which caused the program to check for results two times on each run. A simple change to `if(counter == 60){` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are debugging and you have some modifying sentences on the "expressions" to watch area?
If that happens, they are being evaluated prior or after your code execution randomly in separated threads, so results are odd